# How to change the hint color,underline color hint text,if edit text is empty and unfocused in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I have two edit text.First one is email and the second one is a password field.
When I click login button without filling the both fields, the hint color and underline changes to red color in both fields are an unfocused state.
unfocused state at the landing page, the color should be in blue color[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCZR8.png) 
while clicking login without filling fields in the unfocused state[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nYwi.png.).

This is my requirement.
I have tried all possible ways to achieve this scenario.
But I cant control focused and unfocused state.
Please guide me to solve this issues.

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item> <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item> </style>
```

i want to change the hint color,underline color in unfocused state programmatically.

colors.xml

```
<resources> <color name="primary">#1976d2</color> <color name="primary_dark">#E12929</color> <color name="primary_darker">#CC1D1D</color> <color name="accent">#000000</color> <color name="blue">#1976d2</color> <color name="black">#000000</color> <color name="lightblue">#1976d2</color> <color name="lightgray">#666666</color> </resources>
```

Comment: Use TextInputLayout

Comment: That blue when landing means it is your colorprimary that you mentioned in colors.xml. post your styles.xml and colors.xml

Comment: <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

Comment: Pls edit your question by posting with styles.xml and colors.xml

Comment: i want to change the hint color,underline color in unfocused state programmatically.colors.xml   <resources>
<color name="primary">#1976d2</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#E12929</color>
<color name="primary_darker">#CC1D1D</color>
<color name="accent">#000000</color>
    <color name="blue">#1976d2</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="lightblue">#1976d2</color>
    <color name="lightgray">#666666</color>
    </resources>

Comment: Don't post code in comments, please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like you should try

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="Username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextInputLayout emailInput, passInput;
EditText edtEmail, edtPass;
Button btnLogin;
String hintEmail = "",hintPass="";


emailInput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
passInput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passInput);

edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPass);

btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (edtEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                edtEmail.setHint("please enter Email Address ");
                hintEmail = "please enter Email Address ";
                edtEmail.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorRed));
                emailInput.setHint("");

            }

            if (edtPass.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                edtPass.setHint("please enter Password ");
                hintPass = "please enter Password  ";
                edtPass.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                passInput.setHint("");

            }

        }
    });
    edtEmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            emailInput.setHint(hintEmail);
            edtEmail.setHint("");
            return false;
        }
    });
    edtPass.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            passInput.setHint(hintPass);
            edtPass.setHint("");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh..but i tried that too..i want to change hint color in unfocused state.but in TextInputLayout, the color changes only on focused.

Comment: @user8367573 [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327430/textinputlayout-different-color-for-hint-label-when-not-focused) it will sure help you

Comment: @user8367573 than check the link that i provoded

Comment: than you need to create your OWN @user8367573

Comment: In this github code, the underline color is disappeared. when it is unfocused

Comment: than create your own @user8367573

Comment: shall i use ur mail  id?

Comment: why...any pro..?

Answer (score 0):

Try something below like this,For make error to edittext use`inputLayout.setError("Enther somehting");`after validate your condition you have to remove using `setErrorEnabled(false)`

```
  inputLayout_et = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_newpassword);

  inputLayout_et.setErrorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**hint color**

```
android:textColorHint="@color/red"
```

Comment: you can add it through styles